# Create write and save xml file dynamically in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, writexml

I want to **create xml file and write data from database** in it. file will be created dynamically.

I am storing data in DataTable. Query is `select documentId,documentContent from tblDocument where status = 'F'`

where **documentContent** is xml data.

I have tried following code but its not working,

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string filepath =  ConfigurationManager.Appsetings[Constants.FailedDocuments];
    string filename = "message_"+ dr["documentId"].ToString();
    string content = dr["documentContent"].ToString();
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    xdoc.parse(content);
    xdoc.Load(filepath+filename);
}
```

I am new to this and don't know how to and where to place this code correctly as i want to write `content`

Comment: What do you mean by _"not working"_

Comment: Did you mean `xdoc.Save` instead of `Load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thing:

1. Please post correct code. The XDocument class has no instance method
   "parse", only "Parse". The XDocument class has no instance method
   "Load", only static method "Load".
2. xdoc.Parse(content) would create
   a XDocument from the string. XDocument.Load(filename) would return a
   XDocument loaded from the XML file "filename".

This would do the job:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
   string filepath =  ConfigurationManager.Appsetings[Constants.FailedDocuments];
   string filename = "message_"+ dr["documentId"].ToString();
   string content = dr["documentContent"].ToString();
   XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
   xdoc.Parse(content);
   xdoc.Save(filepath+filename);
}
```

Comment: yes this worked. only small change needed. XDocument xdoc = Xdocument.Parse(content);